# How to remove a custom app from Teams organization store?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I created a custom Teams application, packaged it and uploaded it to the Organization Store. Now when I want to update or delete the application, it says "Something went wrong, please try again later."

Looking at the Chrome Developer Console, it outputs the following error:

```
Failed to delete app, appId: 849e8f73-cbfb-4342-ae30-329b031608f5. Error: {"data":{"errorCode":"AppDefinitionDoesntExist","message":"App doesn't exist in the tenant. UserId: '*removed*', TenantId: '*removed*', AppId: '*removed*'"},"status":404,"config":{"method":"DELETE","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"https://teams.microsoft.com/api/mt/emea/beta/tenant/apps/definitions/849e8f73-cbfb-4342-ae30-329b031608f5/","data":null,"headers":{"X-Skypetoken":"pii","Authorization":"pii","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","X-RingOverride":"ring3_6","x-ms-scenario-id":"233","x-ms-request-id":"pii","x-ms-user-type":"user","x-ms-client-type":"web","x-ms-client-env":"msteams-web-prod-euwe-01","x-ms-client-version":"1415/1.0.0.2018091141","x-ms-session-id":"500e5097-0d22-bd24-3df6-091608ab9dac"},"counter":"apps_definitions_DELETE","decrementNetworkRequests":null,"hostName":"teams.microsoft.com"},"statusText":""}
```

Seems like a previous deletion didn't process correctly, and now my application is in a state of flux. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: You might be right. Can you send an un-redacted version to billbl@microsoft.com?

Comment: I have just sent the unredacted version, thank you very much!

Comment: As an update: in a different tenant, I managed to install the same application twice (with the same package name, same id). Very weird things going on...

Comment: I get a ton of weird behavior like this, can't install app, delete app, or update app. Do you have any updates?